# SQL - phpmyadmin - select field and replace any whitespace bigger than a single space with a space

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

So essentially the problem I have is with a description filed in a table, the description field has been edited with some sort of wysiwig editor. and there are huge spaces between the markup tags.

So lets get all imaginative and call the table: table and the field, description. I want to select all description fields from the table and replace anything bigger than a space with a single space.

Is there any way I can do this within phpmyadmin, e/g using just sql?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup.

```
UPDATE table SET description = REPLACE(description, '  ', ' ');
```

if you only need it once, just run this query ten times :-)

Comment: I will accept this is A solution, I was hoping for something more elegant. I am dealing with some very big white space, I think I could be looking at 50+ runs. Thanks for the suggestion, you can have a +1 for now, and we'll see if there is a better solution to be had.

Answer (score 1):

i will add to fabian answer.  replace 2 space with a null. it should be done in one go and you will be left with the single spaces you need.

```
UPDATE table SET description = REPLACE(description, '  ', '');
```

Comment: really? this works? Why? :-) 2 -> 0, 3 -> 1, 10 -> 8? I don't understand this :)

Comment: Wouldn't `1[space][space]2` become `12`?

Comment: Actually on further inspection, it did create some problems in places, depends if you have an even or odd number of spaces (but didnt matter for most of my markup)